# How to Dynamically Add JButton to JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

In NetBeans, I have used the GUI editor to make a JFrame and I've put a JPanel in the frame.
At the moment, I'm trying to make a new button in the panel when the class constructs.
This is the code I have, but I can't seem to get it to work.
(The first line makes the button, the other lines try to show it.)

```
this.jPanel2.add(new JButton("Test"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.jPanel2.validate();
this.jPanel2.revalidate();
this.jPanel2.repaint();
this.jPanel2.setVisible(true);
this.revalidate();
this.setVisible(true);
this.repaint();
```

I've been googling all night, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2)  The [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) dynamically adds labels.  It is much the same principle.

Comment: Your example code is a little sparse. Maybe you could create an example that is more complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some times when you don't see a button it is a layout manager issue (as in you aren't setting the right properties for the layout manager). You can test this by disabling it:

```
this.jPanel2.setLayoutManager(null);
```

And setting bounds for the button (`JButton.setBounds()`).

If the above fixes your problem, then you need to look into the requirements set by the LayoutManager you are using (see also the answer by Robin).

All the calls to `validate()`, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are not needed to do this.

Comment: -1 for even suggesting null layout manager and manually setting the bounds. There is no valid reason in this case to do this

Comment: I suggested it to confirm it was a mistake in calling the layout manager, not as the solution.

Comment: I added down-vote but removed it when I saw your comment.  Perhaps an edit & expansion is called for.

Comment: Agreed, added a line explaining the actual solution depends on the used layout manager.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the `add` call is sufficient.

Note: a `BorderLayout` can only contain one component in each location. So if you add another component in the `NORTH` location, your button will not be visible.

Second note: by default a `JPanel` does not have a `BorderLayout` but a `FlowLayout`. Have you set a `BorderLayout` on that specific panel ? Otherwise the `BorderLayout#NORTH` constraint is incorrect

All the `validate`,`revalidate`,`repaint` calls can be removed

**Edit**

It seems some sort of validation is needed after all. I was under the impression that Swing should be smart enough to listen for the event when something is added to a `Container`, and  update whatever is necessary (a bit similar to updating a `TableModel` updates the `JTable` based on events, without the need to call `repaint` or the likes on the `JTable`).

However, when trying this in an SSCCE, I came to the following code (different versions, only post the most elaborate version)

- without the scroll-pane, the `validate` calls seem to have no effect. I actually need to call `pack` again to make the new labels visible (not included in the SSCCE, but removing the scrollpane from the code is trivial)
- with the scroll-pane, the `validate` call has an effect

  ```
  import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Container;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.EventQueue;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  public class AddLabelsAtRuntime {

    private int fLabelCounter = 0;
    private JPanel fLabelPanel;
    private final JFrame fTestFrame;

    public AddLabelsAtRuntime() {
      fLabelPanel = new JPanel(  );
      BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout( fLabelPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS );
      fLabelPanel.setLayout( boxLayout );
      fTestFrame = new JFrame( "Dynamically add labels" );
    }

    private JFrame createUI(){

      Container contentPane = fTestFrame.getContentPane();
      contentPane.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( fLabelPanel );
      scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
      contentPane.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

      contentPane.add( createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );

      fTestFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      fTestFrame.pack();
      return fTestFrame;
    }

    private void addLabel(){
      fLabelPanel.add( new JLabel( "Label " + ++fLabelCounter ) );
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel(){
      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(  );
      BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout( buttonPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS );
      buttonPanel.setLayout( boxLayout );

      JButton validateButton = new JButton( "Add + validate" );
      validateButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          addLabel();
          fLabelPanel.validate();
          fTestFrame.validate();
        }
      } );
      buttonPanel.add( validateButton );

      JButton noValidateButton = new JButton( "Add" );
      noValidateButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          addLabel();
        }
      } );
      buttonPanel.add( noValidateButton );

      JButton packButton = new JButton( "Add + pack" );
      packButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
          addLabel();
          fTestFrame.pack();
        }
      } );
      buttonPanel.add( packButton );

      return buttonPanel;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          AddLabelsAtRuntime addLabelsAtRuntime = new AddLabelsAtRuntime();
          addLabelsAtRuntime.createUI().setVisible( true );
        }
      } );

    }

  }
  ```

Comment: I generally find it necessary to call `validate()` - as when adding labels in the example linked above.  Can you provide an SSCCE that adds components dynamically and does not require it?

Comment: I will give it a try tonight, but I do not remember ever needing it

Comment: Look forward to seeing the code.  +1 for the comment on `BorderLayout.NORTH`

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried and I failed :-( . I even need to call `pack` when I do not use a scroll pane to make the new labels visible. With a scroll pane, the `validate` call is sufficient. Seems I was incorrect. Bright side, I learned something new today :-)

Comment: Cool.  Hopefully that is now a 2nd person about these parts that knows it does not require `invalidate()`, `revalidate()` or `repaint()` (common misconceptions) but a single call to `validate()`. Start spreading the word.  ;)

Comment: @Robin for why reason is there `fLabelPanel.validate();` and with     `fTestFrame.validate();` inside `JButton validateButton = new JButton( "Add + validate" );` are you OpenJDK user ???

Comment: @mKorbel OS X user. And as described in the answer, I was experimenting with what calls were needed, and this was the result. Not yet sure why exactly those methods are needed

Comment: @Robin I'm using revalidate & repaint by default, to avoids reading the API, if required methods are correctly implemented ..., in most cases compiled code running on todays PC with good GPU, then there isn't important calculating with these two performance killers for java GUI

Answer (score 0):

Create Dynamic JButton with Image and ActionListener - Java Swing

Create JButton dynamically with Image and the ActionListener . You will be able to change the button height , width horizontal gap and vertical gap in one place.

[you can find more details from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17330368/2380114)

[image]