# Java - How to add new JLabel and JTextPane to JPanel when button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I have a JPanel to which when a button is pressed I want to add a new JLabel and JTextField too. However, I can't seem to get it working.

Is there an issue with my ActionListener, and if not, how could this be achieved?

```
JPanel south = new JPanel();
JButton add = new JButton("Add");
ActionListener addListener = new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           JLabel mL = new JLabel("MOD: ");
           mR.add(mL);
           JTextField mM = new JTextField(10);
           mR.add(mM);
           mR.repaint();

     }

};
add.addActionListener(addListener);
south.add(add);
add(south, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

The layout of the mR panel is a grid layout set to allow multiple rows and two columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `mR.revalidate()` before `repaint();`

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer on a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885855/how-to-dynamically-add-jbutton-to-jpanel/9885927#9885927) for some sample code which dynamically adds a component to a container