# Add JCheckBox to JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jscrollpane, jcheckbox

I'm trying to dynamically add check boxes to a scroll pane depending on what is in my db. Currently i have

```
ResultSet rs = getAvailableUsers();
    try {
        while (rs.next()){
            User temp = new User();
            temp.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            temp.setUserNo(rs.getInt("userno"));
            JCheckBox tempCheckBox = new JCheckBox();
            tempCheckBox.setText(temp.getUsername());
            tempCheckBox.setVisible(true);
            checkBoxes.add(tempCheckBox);

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SelectProjectTeamGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println(checkBoxes);

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    panel.setVisible(true);
    scrollPane.removeAll();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
        panel.add(checkBoxes.get(i));
        //panel.repaint();
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
```

I can see the outline for the scroll pane but none of the checkboxes are there. All the checkboxes are stored in a vector then pulled back out and added to the panel one at a time. Any ideas why it isn't showing anything? I know the checkboxes are in the vector as i've printed it out and seen them all there.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create jCheckBox and add to a jScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234704/dynamically-create-jcheckbox-and-add-to-a-jscrollpane)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- there is an logical issue to call `panel.removeAll();` instead of `scrollPane.removeAll();`
- `JComponent` are added to `JViewport` not to the `JScrollPane`
- then to call (after all Items are added to `JPanel`) `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()` as last code lines in the void
- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), all updates to already visible `Swing GUI` must be done on `Event Dispatch Thread`,  but in other hands `panel.repaint()` notified `Event Dispatch Thread` and correctly

---

- use `JList` (non_editable) or `JTable` (can be editable) with one column (maybe to remove `JTableHeader`) instead of `JPanel` with bunch of `JCheckBoxes` and with un_natural scrolling, note there is stored `Boolean` value in the model, that representing `JCheckBox` in the view

Comment: i call scrollPanel.removeAll() as netbeans creates it, then i recreate using the panel. I'm still a little unsure as to what you mean with all these points.